# Cassandra Startup Error: DseModule.java:103 - org/apache/spark/util/ByteBufferInputStream. Exiting

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I installed Cassandra, DSE after working on DSE Graphs for a while I installed Spark, R. Now I am unable to start DSE. Cassandra process is not starting

I tried disabling Spark and so on. Not sure whats the issue!

```
$ /Users/212500500/dse_510/bin/dse cassandra -g -s
Server will start with the original workload configuration. Edit the dse script to change that (the script that printed this message).
Search: on
Graph: on
Tomcat: Logging to /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/tomcat
Tomcat: Logging to /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/tomcat
SFO1212500500M:dse_510 212500500$ objc[99199]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
17:31:09,605 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/logback.xml]
17:31:09,749 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
17:31:09,753 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/logback.xml]] every 60 seconds.
17:31:09,753 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
17:31:09,764 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.JMXConfiguratorAction - begin
17:31:09,850 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:09,853 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SYSTEMLOG]
17:31:09,896 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@795cd85e - Will use zip compression
17:31:09,906 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:09,928 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SYSTEMLOG] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/system.log
17:31:09,928 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SYSTEMLOG] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/system.log]
17:31:09,930 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:09,930 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DEBUGLOG]
17:31:09,930 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@59fd97a8 - Will use zip compression
17:31:09,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:09,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUGLOG] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/debug.log
17:31:09,931 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DEBUGLOG] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/debug.log]
17:31:09,932 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender]
17:31:09,933 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [ASYNCDEBUGLOG]
17:31:09,938 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DEBUGLOG] to ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNCDEBUGLOG]
17:31:09,938 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNCDEBUGLOG] - Attaching appender named [DEBUGLOG] to AsyncAppender.
17:31:09,938 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNCDEBUGLOG] - Setting discardingThreshold to 0
17:31:10,094 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
17:31:10,095 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
17:31:10,097 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:10,098 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@f5ac9e4 - Adding [file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/SPARK_SERVER_LOGBACK_CONF_FILE_IS_UNDEFINED] to configuration watch list.
17:31:10,098 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Failed to open [file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/SPARK_SERVER_LOGBACK_CONF_FILE_IS_UNDEFINED]
17:31:10,098 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@f5ac9e4 - Adding [file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/graph/conf/logback-gremlin-server.xml] to configuration watch list.
17:31:10,101 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:10,101 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [GremlinServerFileAppender]
17:31:10,104 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator] for [evaluator] property
17:31:10,122 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@123ef382 - Will use zip compression
17:31:10,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:10,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[GremlinServerFileAppender] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/gremlin.log
17:31:10,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[GremlinServerFileAppender] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/gremlin.log]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SYSTEMLOG] to Logger[ROOT]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [ASYNCDEBUGLOG] to Logger[ROOT]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [GremlinServerFileAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SLF4JAuditWriterAppender]
17:31:10,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:10,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@dbf57b3 - Will use zip compression
17:31:10,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SLF4JAuditWriterAppender] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/audit/audit.log
17:31:10,126 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SLF4JAuditWriterAppender] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/audit/audit.log]
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [SLF4JAuditWriter] to INFO
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [SLF4JAuditWriter] to false
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SLF4JAuditWriterAppender] to Logger[SLF4JAuditWriter]
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DroppedAuditEventAppender]
17:31:10,127 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@384ad17b - Will use zip compression
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DroppedAuditEventAppender] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/audit/dropped-events.log
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DroppedAuditEventAppender] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/audit/dropped-events.log]
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [DroppedAuditEventLogger] to INFO
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [DroppedAuditEventLogger] to false
17:31:10,128 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DroppedAuditEventAppender] to Logger[DroppedAuditEventLogger]
17:31:10,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cassandra] to DEBUG
17:31:10,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.thinkaurelius.thrift] to ERROR
17:31:10,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
17:31:10,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [SolrValidationErrorAppender]
17:31:10,129 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@61862a7f - Will use zip compression
17:31:10,130 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
17:31:10,130 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SolrValidationErrorAppender] - Active log file name: /Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/solrvalidation.log
17:31:10,130 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[SolrValidationErrorAppender] - File property is set to [/Users/212500500/dse_510/logs/cassandra/solrvalidation.log]
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [SolrValidationErrorLogger] to ERROR
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [SolrValidationErrorLogger] to false
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [SolrValidationErrorAppender] to Logger[SolrValidationErrorLogger]
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.metrics.MetricsWriteEventListener] to DEBUG
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.CassandraSolrConfig] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.handler.component] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.solr.update] to WARN
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.lucene.index] to INFO
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.cryptsoft] to OFF
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
17:31:10,131 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@441772e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,249  DseModule.java:90 - Loading DSE module
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,493  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,782  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,811  Config.java:481 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor=null; authenticator=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator; authorizer=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=640; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/Users/212500500/dse_510/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; continuous_paging=org.apache.cassandra.config.ContinuousPagingConfig@9caca531; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@ff684e1; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/Users/212500500/dse_510/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=127.0.0.1; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=1; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=127.0.0.1; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/Users/212500500/dse_510/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@23aa363a; trickle_fsync=true; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,812  DatabaseDescriptor.java:366 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,813  DatabaseDescriptor.java:420 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 1024MB
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,813  DatabaseDescriptor.java:424 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 1024MB
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,838  RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,839  DatabaseDescriptor.java:717 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,861  DseDelegateSnitch.java:40 - Setting my workloads to [Cassandra, Search, Graph]
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,867  DseConfigYamlLoader.java:38 - Loading settings from file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,957  DseConfig.java:382 - Load of settings is done.
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,971  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,973  DseDelegateSnitch.java:42 - Initialized DseDelegateSnitch with workloads [Cassandra, Search, Graph], delegating to com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:10,995  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,042  DseConfig.java:402 - CQL slow log is enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,043  DseConfig.java:403 - CQL system info tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,043  DseConfig.java:404 - Resource level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,043  DseConfig.java:405 - Database summary stats are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,043  DseConfig.java:406 - Cluster summary stats are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,043  DseConfig.java:407 - Histogram data tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,044  DseConfig.java:408 - User level latency tracking is not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,044  DseConfig.java:410 - Spark cluster info tables are not enabled
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,044  DseConfig.java:444 - Cql solr query paging is: off
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,046  DseConfig.java:459 - Server ID:A4-5E-60-F4-1B-DB
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,334  GraphYamlConfigurationReader.java:185 - Loading graph settings from file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
INFO  [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,335  GraphYamlConfigurationReader.java:189 - Opened stream on file:/Users/212500500/dse_510/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml
ERROR [main] 2017-04-27 17:31:11,385  DseModule.java:103 - org/apache/spark/util/ByteBufferInputStream. Exiting...
```

$ ps -ef |grep dse
    0   724     1   0 Mon09PM ??         0:05.04 /usr/sbin/systemsoundserverd
348149448 99945  1448   0  5:40PM ttys001    0:00.00 grep dse

Answer (score 1):

I had saperately installed Apache Spark. Problem went away when I removed Spark (unset SPARK_HOME variable) and then restarted DSE Cassandra.